# Limits, integrals, continuity

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Define:
$$J(x)=\int^{h(x)}_{g(x)} f(x,y)dy$$

I want to know whether or not $J(x)$ is continuous in $x$. I know that  $h(x)$, $f(x,y)$, $g(x)$ are all continuous in $x$, and $f(x,y)$ is continuous in $y$. What should I do?

Second, related question:
If either $h(x)$ or $g(x)$ are *not* continuous in $x$, how can I compute:
$$\lim_{x\to n} J(x)$$

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The quantity $\displaystyle\int^{h(x)}_{g(x)} f(x)=(h(x)-g(x))f(x)$ is most probably **not** what you want to ask about, please check.

Comment: Of course, you are correct, thank you - corrected now.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: Right, but as @JimmyK4542 points out below, I can only use that if I know that $f(x)$, $g(x)$, $h(x)$ are *differentiable*, rather than merely continuous.

Comment: Then https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Continuity_under_Integral_Sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer to the first question.

Define
$$J(x)=\int^{h(x)}_{g(x)} f(x,y) dy \tag{-1}$$

So $J(x)$ is continuous if $f(x,y),f(y,x) g(x), h(x)$ are continuous at $x$.

then

$$\frac{dJ}{dx}(x)= f(x,h(x))h'(x)-f(x,g(x))g'(x)+\int^{h(x)}_{g(x)} f^{(1,0)}(x,y) dy \tag{0}$$

So $J'(x)$ is continuous if $f(x,y), g(x), h(x)$ are twice continuous at $x$ and $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $y$.

EDIT: now let us deal with the second question what if $h(x),g(x)$ are not continuous?

Supposed that $h(x)$ is not continuous at $x_1$, i.e.,$h(x_1+0)-h(x_1-0) = a(x_1)\gt 0$,and $g(x)$ is continuous at $x_1$,$h(x_1-0)>g(x_1+0)=g(x_1-0)=g(x_1)$,

then

$$J(x_1-0)=\int^{h(x_1-0)}_{g(x_1)} f(x_1,y) dy \tag{1}$$
$$J(x_1+0)=\int^{h(x_1+0)}_{h(x_1-0)} f(x_1,y) dy +\int^{h(x_1-0)}_{g(x_1)} f(x,y) dy \tag{2}$$

Thus
$$J(x_1+0)\not = J(x_1-0)$$

Therefore we can not properly calculate the value of $J(x_1)$ when $x_1$ is a discontinuous point of $h(x)$ or $g(x)$.

But if $x$ is neither a discontinuous point of $g(x)$ nor of $h(x)$, then $J(x)$ of eq.(0) is fine.

Comment: How do we know that $g$ and $h$ are differentiable?

Comment: Thanks - but my integrand was $f(x)$, not $f(y)$. Doesn't that make a difference?
Edit: Urgh, that's a stupid thing to say, sorry. I will change the OP... I meant something slightly different.

Comment: @JimmyK4542. When I started to type the answer. $f(y,x),g(x),h(x)$ are all assumed to be continuous in $x$.

Comment: Ok, I get you now - thanks very much. I will tick your answer. I am still looking for the answer to the second question - should I create a new question to ask it? (I am relatively new to stackexchange)

Comment: Yes, but $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ being continuous does not necessarily imply that they are differentiable.

Comment: Let me try to answer the second one.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Presumably I also require that $f(x,y)$ is *twice* continuously differentiable in $x$ (since differentiation under the integral sign seems to require that).

Comment: @JimmyK4542 you raise a good point regarding $g(x)$ and $h(x)$.

Comment: "So it seems to me that $J(x)$ is continuous if $f(y,x),f(x,y),g(x),h(x)$ are continuous in $x$." Hmmm... how is this related to the formula just before that?

Comment: @Did Thanks for the comment.  I changed the wording a little. I hope that it is better now.

Comment: Still seems unrelated to (0).

Comment: I tried on more time...